# How to choose threshold in probabilistic multi-label classification?

Tags: classification, threshold, multilabel

My problem is to tag some texts with some labels. That is multi-label classification in ML.

I did `predict` with Catboost classifier and get some results of binary type.

Now I am going to make `predict_proba` to predict the probability that the object belongs to the given classes.

How does this probability compara to my previous binary result? How should I choose the treshold: individually for each label, or global one?